# How to use VBA to copy a filename of an Excel workbook opened with VBA and use it in a save-as function for current workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a set of workbooks that contain data that needs to be copied to a new version of the workbook.   I found a macro that I added to the new workbook that will open the open file dialogue to allow you to select a file.  It then opens the file, copies specific cells to the new workbook and then closes the workbook.

```
Sub CopyDataToNewWB()
    Dim FileToOpen As Variant
    Dim OpenBook As Workbook
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Copy Data", FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*),*xls*")
        
                            
            If FileToOpen <> False Then
                Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
                OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("A5:o199").Copy
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Calculator").Range("A5").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("AO5:AR34").Copy
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Calculator").Range("AO5").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                OpenBook.Application.CutCopyMode = False
        
                OpenBook.Close False
            End If
    
    Application.Goto Reference:=Worksheets("Calculator").Range("A5"), _
 Scroll:=False
 
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 
End Sub
```

I would like to get the filename of the old workbook that was opened and use it in a save-as function to save over top of the old file.  I would like to keep the new file open so that I can repeat the process on subsequent files. Of course I will be working on a backup directory of the original files and not the originals themselves.

I have been searching for ways to do this and for code it incorporate but with my minimal knowledge of VBA, I struggle to figure out hoe to incorporate anything and make it all work. I appreciate everyone's help once again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Public Function provided by @Siddarth Rout worked flawlessly once I figured out how to use it.  The entire code he provided only displayed a message box with the filename so I had to figure out how to get this into the "Save As" dialogue box. But this was an extra step I did not need in the end.

It took me a while to figure how to make it work but I ended up using SaveCopyAs instead and creating a new folder and incorporating the path into the code. This way I avoided having to accept the filename and find a way to bypass the "File Exists..." box.  BTW, I did try "Application.DisplayAlerts = False" to eliminate this but it would not work for me.

However, saving a copy of the file to a new folder using the name derived from the Siddarth's Function worked great.

I also added a "Kill" function to delete the file after the contents were copied.  This allowed me to open the first file in the directory without having to select a file (every file needs to be copied)

Here is the final code that works great.

The following code does everything I was looking for and I would also like to thank others here that posted Snippets I was able to use and learn a little from. Sorry but there so many pages I was flipping around through that there is no way to list names. Great community.

```
Sub CopyDataToNewWB()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim FileToOpen As Variant
    Dim OpenBook As Workbook
    Dim fPath As String

    fPath = "d:\Your\New\Save\Location\"
    FileToOpen = Dir("D:\Dir\Containing\Files\To\Copy\", vbNormal)
    
    
    If FileToOpen <> False Then
        Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
        OpenBook.Worksheets("Calculator").Range("A5:O199").Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Calculator").Range("A5").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        OpenBook.Worksheets("Calculator").Range("AO5:AR34").Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Calculator").Range("AO5").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        OpenBook.Application.CutCopyMode = False
        
        OpenBook.Close False
    End If
    
    Kill (GetFilenameFromPath(FileToOpen))
    
    Application.Goto Reference:=Worksheets("Calculator").Range("A5"), _
 Scroll:=True
 
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs (fPath & GetFilenameFromPath(FileToOpen))

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub

Public Function GetFilenameFromPath(ByVal FilePath As String) As String
    If Right(FilePath, 1) <> "\" And Len(FilePath) > 0 Then
        GetFilenameFromPath = GetFilenameFromPath(Left(FilePath, Len(FilePath) - 1)) + _
                              Right(FilePath, 1)
    End If
End Function
```

With this code attached to a button, it allows me to click and just wait for it to complete and then click again for the next file.  Then next step will be to find a way to have the macro repeat X number of times so that I don't have to monitor the process.

With a little modification, I will be able to make almost any retroactive change to a series of Excel files update them with ease. Lovin'VB!

Comment: I have discovered a small problem that I will research and try to solve.  Using the code ```FileToOpen = Dir("D:\Dir\Containing\Files\To\Copy\", vbNormal) ``` only works after you have first used the code ```FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="File to copy from", FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*),*xls*")```. I am hoping to figure out an if statement to allow the first one to be tried first and if it does not work, to then use the second code. I will post results when successful.

Answer (score 1):

When you close the OpenBook do:

```
OpenBook.Close savechanges = True
```

Comment: Hi Nuno,  Thank you, but I need to save-as the original file using the name from the OpenBook and not just save the OpenBook.

Comment: Hi @DryBSMT. Hope I can help.
Could you then store the workbook name as: `name_workbook = OpenBook.name`. Then saving it like `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=name_workbook` after closing OpenBook?

Comment: Thanks @Nuno.  I just finished posting the complete solution, at least for my needs. Thanks for your suggestions though.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to get the filename of the old workbook that was opened

You already have that in the code? `FileToOpen` will have the name of the file which you opened?

If you want to extract just the file name then here is an example.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim FileToOpen
    
    FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Copy Data", _
                                             FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*),*xls*")
    
    If FileToOpen = False Then Exit Sub
    
    MsgBox GetFilenameFromPath(FileToOpen)
End Sub

Public Function GetFilenameFromPath(ByVal FilePath As String) As String
    If Right(FilePath, 1) <> "\" And Len(FilePath) > 0 Then
        GetFilenameFromPath = GetFilenameFromPath(Left(FilePath, Len(FilePath) - 1)) +  _
                              Right(FilePath, 1)
    End If
End Function
```